# How to tell if a sequence is bounded/upper/lower/etc?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not getting the concepts of bounded when it comes to sequences. Can someone tell me these answers and explain why they are the answer?

> Choose the best description for each sequence: Bounded from Above, Bounded from Below, Both Bounded from Above and Below, or None of These:
>
> $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$
>
> $b_n = -4-3n$
>
> $c_n = 5 + \frac{n}{2}$
>
> $d_n = (-2)^n$

(original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZmt0.png)

Comment: Is this a practice quiz?  Where are you encountering this?  What are the tests you already know about to determine whether something is bounded or not.  Have you tried writing out some example values for each series?  Answering some of these questions (and others like these) is considered "context" for a question like yours, and is vital to avoiding downvotes and question suspension or closure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the $n$ is counting from 1 to $\infty$ for all four, it is clear that: ${a_n}$ is bounded both above and below, since for $n=1$, $a_1 = -1$, and that for $n=\infty$, $a_\infty \rightarrow 0$. For ${b_n}$, the sequence if bounded above by any value greater than -7, since $b_1 =-7$ and the sequence ${b_n}$ is monotonically decreasing. ${c_n}$ is bounded below, since its lowest value is $5+\frac{1}{2}$, and increases infinitely from there on. Lastly, ${d_n}$ is unbounded. We see this because $\vert {b_k} \vert > \vert {b_{k-1}} \vert$, but ${b_k} > {b_{k-1}}$ is false half of the time. In other words, its oscillates and the oscillations get larger and larger each time.